# Append Dataframe columns as a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 500+ columns and I want to just store the values from certain columns that contain the string "valid" in their names and store them in a new empty list.

I have used `df1=df.filter(regex='valid').values.tolist()`

My earlier method was - `df1=[df['1valid'],df['2valid'],...df['nvalid']]`

I'm unable to differentiate between the two. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`df.filter(regex='valid')` returns DataFrame whose column contains pattern `valid`. `df.values` return a Numpy representation of the DataFrame. `numpy.tolist()` convert the Numpy array to Python list.

`df1=[df['1valid'],df['2valid'],...df['nvalid']]` is a list of Series.